# Obtaining additional profile information with ASP.NET Identity and Microsoft account

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm attempting to integrate an MVC5 application with Microsoft account authentication, and as a proof of concept, I'm using the default ASP.net templates with ASP.net Identity.

For the basic application setup, I've used this excellent tutorial: http://www.benday.com/2014/02/25/walkthrough-asp-net-mvc-identity-with-microsoft-account-authentication/. I customized using my Microsoft developer portal client ID and secret, and set up the "fake" domain on my localhost, but aside from that, the solution is 100% stock Microsoft.

I'm able to log in; the challenge now is obtaining the profile information (email, first name, last name, etc). The Windows Live / Microsoft Account authentication does not seem to be well-documented. I've found some articles on MSDN that point me in the right direction (adding fields to the identity tables, but that article didn't reference owin; getting additional information from Facebook; a list of the extra information you can pull from FB, Twitter, and Google, but not how to do it; etc.)

None of these resources are giving me what I really need, which is a list of the information I can pull from Live/Microsoft, and how to pull it.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh826537.aspx

Comment: That points me in the right direction I think - use case is different from mine but it does seem to document the use of the API in a different context. I will report back. Thanks!